# Javascript / jQuery how to filter object with retaining its keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have something like this: getting another object without some properties. I already have a working solution:

```
var s = {
 a: 3,
 b: 2,
 c: -1,
 d: 8,
 e: -1
};

var f = {};
jQuery.map(s, function(v,k) {
    if (v != -1)
    {
        f[k] = v;
    }
});

output is:
     a: 3,
     b: 2,
     d: 8,
```

its fine but isnt there more simpler sollution? Maybe with `jQuery` but neither `.map`, `.filter`, `.grep` methods helped me so far!

Comment: If you're willing to use Lodash, you can use [`omitBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omitBy)

Comment: Why not JS `for (var k in o) o[k] !== -1 && tmp[k] = o[k]`

Comment: I want to have something that doesnt need extra "f" variable! I mean, a .map, .each method would return it$

Comment: What do you mean by simpler solution?

Comment: Also I just realised, your code is working fine and objective of this question is optimisation. So Should this not belong to CodeReviews?

Comment: what means without `f`? just delete the properties with value `-1`.

Comment: @Rajesh This would get closed on Code Review as example code. See the [topics](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page there.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
var s = {
 a: 3,
 b: 2,
 c: -1,
 d: 8,
 e: -1
};
for(var k in s){
  if(s[k] == -1){
    delete(s[k]);
  }
}
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like this

```js
var s = {
 a: 3,
 b: 2,
 c: -1,
 d: 8,
 e: -1
};


for (var property in s) {
    if (s[property]!=-1) {
      console.log(property+":"+s[property]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) for deleting a property of an object.

```js
var s = { a: 3, b: 2, c: -1, d: 8, e: -1 }

Object.keys(s).forEach(function (k) {
    if (s[k] === -1) {
        delete s[k];
    }
});
console.log(s);
```